# how to solve this The server does not support version 3.0 of the J2EE Web module specification.?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

i am trying to deploy the jsp-servlet application in tomcat5.5 but shows this error when i try to deploy in to the server.

```
 The server does not support version 3.0 of the J2EE Web module specification.
```

but i am able to do it tomcat 7.0 and above. i think it is the version of servlet. Please help me how to over come this.

thanks
Antony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ways to solve the problem:

1 Change version to 2.5 to run in tomcat 5.5

2 Run your application with version 3.0 in tomcat 7

No other solutions I know

Comment: Change version of web application in web.xml

Answer (score 1):

see the link below for details:

http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

tomcat5.5.x supports servlet/jsp spec  2.4/2.0  (Does not support annotations)

You need to upgrade to tomcat7.x to be able to run servlet/jsp spec 3.0/2.2

Comment: but if change it to 204/2.0 than annotations are not working,throws exception.

Comment: annotations are not supported on version 2.4. tomcat5.5 is a really old version anyway and why not use the latest stable version tomcat7 and v7 is the only one that supports servlet 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Tomcat5.x it supports servlet version 2.4 specification.
servlet specification 3.0 acceptable from Tomcat 6.x and higher, that is why you are able to run the application by Tomcat7.